# Android app not even starting in redmi note3 miui

Tags: android

I have developed an android app. It is working fine in every android phone except Redmi Note3 MIUI phones. It gets installed but doesn't start. I think it doesn't even get loaded in the RAM as there is no crash report.

I don't get a message like 'Unfortunately, your app has crashed.' 
I click on the app, a blank white screen appears and I come back to menu screen. That's it.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please post your stack trace over here.

Comment: Did you try installing the apk directly instead of USB?

Comment: You should look at the logcat for any clues as to the cause of the problem. You should also add `Log.d()` statements to your app in order to see if your `onCreate()` method is called.

Answer (score 2):

There are a serious issue of Redmi devices. I personally have faced similar error.

After Marshmallow, Android make security level more stick.

If you are going to use System Window then Redmi devices is closed suddenly without showing any message like "Unfortunately, your app has crashed".

What you have to do, you have to add permission to access System Window Alert in **manifest.xml**

Like,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answer. I found a specific problem that was causing it to crash my app. I used ImageFlipper in my HomeActivity. There were certain images in ImageFlipper that was causing the app to crash. I removed those few images and now my app works fine. I still don't know the exact reason why it behaved abnormally with Redmi devices